# Cigarette smoking rates at city level

Tags: data-request, medical, demographics, south-america

I'm looking for international cigarette (or tobacco) smoking rates at the city level. So far I've only seen international rates at the country level. Great would be global rates at the city/regional level, but first choice would be South America, and if at the country level: Peru or Colombia. Second choice would be Pakistan or India.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I move away from the first choice countries, Peru or Colombia, my next choice would be India or Pakistan. For India, I did find a WHO report ([PDF](https://www.who.int/tobacco/surveillance/survey/gats/GATS_India_2016-17_FactSheet.pdf)) that has smoking rates of states, from 2016-2017.

AND, if I truncate the web address, I find a list of available countries:

https://www.who.int/tobacco/surveillance/survey/gats/

(but no Colombia or Peru)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It requires some work to assemble the results, but a great resource is the [Global school-based student health survey (GSHS)](https://www.who.int/ncds/surveillance/gshs/datasets/en/) from the World Health Organization.

Some other resources:

Country level data is available from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prevalence_of_tobacco_use)

Smoking rates for US states is available at [CDC](https://chronicdata.cdc.gov/Survey-Data/Behavioral-Risk-Factor-Data-Tobacco-Use-2011-to-pr/wsas-xwh5)

The US cities with the most smoking are listed at [Cities With the Most Smokers](https://247wallst.com/special-report/2017/06/22/cities-with-the-highest-smoking-rates/2/)

Seven Latin American Cities are given at [BMJ Journals](https://tobaccocontrol.bmj.com/content/19/6/457)

Answer (score 1):

This paper has some aggregate rates for 4 cities in Peru (but not useful for me):

> Lima, Tumbes, Urban Puno, Puno

[*Low cigarette smoking prevalence in peri-urban Peru: results from a population-based study of tobacco use by self-report and urine cotinine*](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5521105/)

doi: [10.1186/s12971-017-0137-8](https://dx.doi.org/10.1186%2Fs12971-017-0137-8)